# main.CRITICAL: Class Company\Modulename\Block\Index does not exist

Tags: magento2, blocks

I'm creating a very simple module and I am missing something.

The module page will not load, and I see these errors:

```
[2020-12-11 15:51:21] main.CRITICAL: Class Company\Modulename\Block\Index does not exist [] []
[2020-12-11 15:51:21] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Company\Modulename\Block\Index [] []
```

I believe the problem must be somewhere in these two files and the name of them

**Company/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/mapsearch_index_index.xml**

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Mapsearch bbb</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Company\Modulename\Block\Index" name="mapsearch_index" template="Company_Modulename::mapsearch.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Company/Modulename/Block/Index/Index.php**

```
namespace Company\Modulename\Block;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Index extends Template
{

    public function __construct(Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }

    public function getNeData()
    {
        return $this->getNe();
    }

    public function getNwData()
    {
        return $this->getNw();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in block structure of this file - `Company/Modulename/Block/Index/Index.php`

It should be in `Company/Modulename/Block/Index.php`

Basically, have to remove `Index` directory and have to move `Index.php` in `Company/Modulename/Block/` directory.

Comment: lol.. thank you! 2 hours wasted. isn't programming fun?

Comment: @lms_forever happy coding :)